# Pick a number say 3 so you can enter 3 numbers then substract the maximum from the min

Tags: c++, c++17

I tried changing a lot of integers and stuff but it didn't work and it gives me a random number like 53289432 even tho lets say i put in 3:5,1,2 it should output 3 since 5-2 is 3.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
 int n;
 cin>>n;
 int x[n];
 int mn;
 int mx;

 for(int i=1;i<n;i++)
 {
     cin>>x[i];
     for(int j=1;j<n;j++)
     {
     if(x[i]>x[j]);
     }
 {
    x[i]=mn;
 }
 }
  for(int i=1;i<n;i++)
 {
    
   for(int j=1;j<n;j++)
     {
     if(x[i]<x[j]);
     }
 {
    x[i]=mx;
 }
 }
 cout<<mx-mn;
 
 
 
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to have your `if`s do nothing?  And `mn` and `mx` aren't ever initialized.  Plus you're using a variable-length array.

Comment: `int x[n];` is not standard C++.  See [Why aren't variable-length arrays part of the C++ standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard)

Comment: hazey, Certainly `for(int j=1;j<n;j++)` --> `for(int j=1;j<i;j++)` as a step to fixing one of many problems.  What do you think `if(x[i]>x[j]);` does?

Comment: Save time, enable all warnings.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an array:

```
int smallest = 0;
int largest  = 0;
std::cout << "Enter quantity: ";
int quantity;
std::cin >> quantity;
if (quantity < 1)
{
  std::cerr << "Invalid quantity.\n";
  return 1;
}
std::cout << "Enter number: ";
std::cin >> smallest;
largest = smallest;
for (int i = 1; i < quantity; ++i)
{
  std::cout << "Enter number: ";
  int number;
  std::cin >> number;
  if (number < smallest) smallest = number;
  if (number > largest)  largest  = number;
}
std::cout << "maximum from minimum: " << (smallest - largest) << "\n";
std::cout << "minimum from maximum: " << (largest - smallest) << "\n";
```

The above code uses a *running minimum/maximum*, so no arrays are needed.

No need for variable length arrays or having to figure out the array capacity at compile time.

Comment: Nice. Not much left to do except `"substract the maximum from the min" (which seems odd - I'd expect the other way) and cope with overflow potential.

Answer (score 0):

Your code carries several holes,

Firstly,

```
for(int i=1;i<n;i++)
{ 
  cin>>x[i];
```

This won't take n integers, it will only take (n-1) integers as input. You need to initialise `i=0`, for n integers;

Secondly,

```
for(int i=1;i<n;i++)
{
   cin>>x[i];
   for(int j=1;j<n;j++)
   {
     if(x[i]>x[j]); //This will compare with garbage when i=1 and j>1
   }
   {
     x[i]=mn;
   }
}
```

Your comparison, will only be valid for first iteration of `i=1 and j=1`, after `j>1`, it will pick garbage value, since, you haven't taken any input yet.

It is suggested, to first take all the inputs, then do the comparison, or other operations.

**Here is my solution**

I think this is what you are trying to do!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <climits>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int n;
  cin>>n;
 
  int x[n];
  int mn;
  int mx;
  
  //First take the inputs in array x

  for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
     cin>>x[i];
  }

  //Find maximum and store it in mx

  mx = INT_MIN; //This stores minimum in mx variable (climits)
  for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
  {
     if(mx<x[j])
       mx=x[j];
  }

  //Find minimum and store it in mn

  mn = INT_MAX; //This stores maximum in mn variable (climits)
  for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
  {
     if(mn>x[j])
       mn=x[j];
  }
  int ans = mx - mn;
  cout<<ans<<endl;
 
}
```

There is a better solution where you don't use extra space(array), and by using only 2 variables, you can find the difference. But I would recommend you to first understand this concept, and take a look, how array works, before moving towards any optimised solution.

Comment: Try avoid giving way complete code. The answer is too long to comprehend.

Comment: I was just, highlighting his mistakes, so that he could understand better.